# Use Chef to set DNS before running the rest of a cookbook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra, devops

I'm following the chef tour and learning how to troubleshoot chef (https://learn.chef.io/modules/keep-your-cookbooks-up-to-date#/). Problem is every distro I use is getting that 10.0.2.3 resolv.conf file.

I've tried following this post:
https://serverfault.com/questions/453185/vagrant-virtualbox-dns-10-0-2-3-not-working

The solution only works for existing VM's however. In my cookbook I created a template resolv.conf.erb and at the beginning of my default.rb I put this code:

template '/etc/resolv.conf' do
  source 'resolv.conf.erb'
  mode '644'
end

However, no matter how I try and configure it (default.rb is the first thing ran by my policyfile), chef is asking ubuntu to wget from omnitruck.chef.io before it deploy's my resolv.conf template. Here's all of default.rb:

```
#
# Cookbook:: base
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2019, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

include_recipe 'hardening::default'

template '/etc/resolv.conf' do
  source 'resolv.conf.erb'
  mode '644'
end

file '/etc/motd' do
  content node['base']['message']
end
```

What else do I need to configure to make chef deploy resolv.conf before it tries to wget?

Comment: please clarify your question -- would you like to configure your dns resolver before chef bootstrap runs (before chef installs itself) or would you like your recipe to the first one to run (be the first in the run-list)?

Comment: I believe it would be before Chef installs. I've been reading through it and I guess the first thing its doing is installing the chef client on the image and that's where its making its wget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chef performs its bootstrap by downloading and installing chef on the node and only then executes chef-client with the recipes in the run-list. thus, you will need your node to be configured with your favorite dns resolver before chef starts its bootstrap.

if you are using [`vagrant`](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant), you can try [`vagrant-dns`](https://github.com/BerlinVagrant/vagrant-dns) or [build your own vagrant basebox](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html)

Comment: It doesn't sound like there is a way to set it before bootstrapping the VM. Crud.

Comment: @LogicFailure_2019: sure there is :) just configure the dns resolver on your node image and create a new image for you to use.

Comment: that makes sense. But I'm a newb and my google-fu is weak. I know the ovf's are saved at C:/Users/<myuser>/.vagrant.d/boxes on windows. Are you suggesting copying one of those? Or is there a way in virtualbox (or vagrant) to modify the image? Each time I run vagrant up it seems like it pulls the base image with 10.0.0.23.

Comment: I think I've found the guide I need: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html. Thanks MrRoth!

Comment: @LogicFailure_2019: i've update my post and if it answer your question, please mark as resolved :)